# Cases in SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case-statement

I have a Query In MySQL
`Give all managers of First Bank Corporation a 10 percent salary raise unless the salary become greater than $100000; in such cases, give only a 3 percent raise.`

In my Database I have following Table on which i have to work on

- Employee(emp_name, street, city)
- Works(emp_name, company_name, salary)
- Company(company_name, city)
- Manages(emp_name, manager_name)`

I have done half part of the query, now I have no idea how to do its other part

```
Update Works
    set Salary= salary + salary * 0.10
    where company_name = 'First Bank Corporation' AND
          emp_name IN (Select manager_name from Manages) AND
          salary > 100000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE ...
   SET salary = CASE
                  WHEN salary * 1.10 > 100000
                  THEN salary * 1.03
                  ELSE salary * 1.10
                END
 WHERE ...
```

-or-

```
UPDATE ...
   SET salary = salary * CASE
                           WHEN salary * 1.10 > 100000
                           THEN 1.03
                           ELSE 1.10
                         END
 WHERE ...
```